# Setting Color for Category Lines

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a view that displays data from several categories, where the category (bug severity in my case) is color-coded into the background color of individual entries. Now I'd like to apply the same background color to the category line itself.

As the column setting the background color for the rest of the line isn't displayed in category rows, the setting isn't applied. Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/0/2765b9380021c666852572d800589f9d?OpenDocument

> Here is an awkward method that works to color your category rows
>   differently.
>
> 1. Put a column before all the categorized columns. This will be your color column. Check the Use Value as Color property of the column
>      properties.
> 2. Use one of the functions below:
>
>    @If(@IsCategory("any")="any";any;1:1:1)
>      @If(@IsCategory("x")="y";z;1:1:1)
>
> Note: in the function above, where the word "any" appears, or "x" "y"
>   and "z", it can be anything, matching or not. It will always evaluate
>   to false. If you try just @IsCategory, it will error out because that
>   doesn't return true. And no match you try will ever cause a true
>   comparison.
>
> That said, the result is that all rows will be colored black if they
>   are not categories. This overrides the default text color. If you want
>   another color than black, then adjust the 1:1:1 accordingly
>   (red:green:blue up to 255 for each position, red= 255:0:0)
>
> Now go to any column and set the text color to the row you want your
>   categorized rows to appear in, and click Apply to All. Voila!

Comment: I've seen that one -- this sets the color for *all* category rows to the same value. I'm looking for a way to assign colors to individual categories (i.e. the "> Severe" line should get a red background, the "> Normal" line a yellow one etc.)

Comment: @SimonRichter, ok, it was worth a shot.  Unfortunately it looks like the category rows were left out of that feature.  I think it makes sense given that they are a special type of column in a view, though it would be nice if that could've been documented (I couldn't find anything specific).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure out how to do this programmatically and then I wondered, why not just borrow from the mail template? I'd like to suggest you check into how the ColorProfile is used there to allow users to change their color preferences based on a field value (sender name) and see if it can be done for your case.

Or, have them either access the view via a browser client or XPages in the Notes client and assign a class to that  dependent on the severity.

You could build the category column formula with HTML such that when it is severe the value is `"<tr class='severe'><td>CategoryNameValueHere</td></tr>"` or something along those lines, right?